# How to resolve the null pointer exception when entering elements from user to store in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

In the following program, I am trying to get values in an array from user. 
However, I am getting NullPointerException after entering only two values.
Can someone explain why I am getting this exception?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MemoriseMe{

    static int arr1[],count;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader brObj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int firstQuery =Integer.parseInt(brObj.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the elements : ");  
        String line = brObj.readLine(); // to read multiple integers line
        String[] strs = line.trim().split("\\s+");

        for(int i =0;i<firstQuery;i++)
        {
            arr1[i]=Integer.parseInt(brObj.readLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `arr1` is never initialized, and is `null` -- you will get a `NullPointerException` when you try to access it with an index. It seems like you want it to have a length of `firstQuery`, so:

```
arr1 = new int[firstQuery];
```